# a question about loading geojson data to leaflet

Tags: leaflet, postgis

I have a question for you!
I can just connect PostGIS and I can show my data in my browser with alert (response), but my problem is that I can not bring them to the leaflet and I get an ERROR: Uncaught Error: Invalid GeoJSON object.

I researched a lot on the internet but it was futile.
that would be nice if you can help me.

my codes are:

```
 $.ajax({url:'webmapp.php',success:function (response) {
      var jsnEgales= JSON.parse(response);
       testLayer=L.geoJSON(jsnEgales).addTo(map);
         map.fitBounds(testLayer.getBounds());
     },
     error:function (xhr,status,error) {
         alert("ERROR:"+error);
     }
 });
```

that would be very nice if you can help me

Comment: pls post your data structure / example

Comment: Can you visualize the data as GeoJSON? Or are you retrieving the postgis geometry in binary format?

Comment: Please edit your question with the value you're seeing in this alert of yours and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

There's a handy Leaflet plugin which will do the ajax / geoJson for you - https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax

The code can look like this:

```
testLayer = new L.geoJSON.AJAX('webmapp.php').addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(testLayer.getBounds());
```